# Is it possible to send text to a specific process without making it active?

Tags: autohotkey

Well I was bored, so I wanted to create something i never tried before. I wanted to create a program in which would provide with the process name for example: "Notepad.exe", I assume that is already open, so what i want to do is to have the program sent a text like "I like cats" directly to the said process.
I want it to not make the said window active, but still want this text to apear in the said process.

I tried using AutoHotkey to handle sending text and detecting if the process is open. It kinda worked but firstly, yeah it found the process but it didn't sent a text to it. It just seemed that it couldn't send a text to it, so i decided to make this procces active and then send a text to it, which was already against my first idea, anyways it didn't work too. I will provide the code I used later in here. When I tried to look it up on google i found myself unable to phrase correctly, so i ended up in here looking for help. Looking into the future plans i want the program to be able to do something more advance too. If the AutoHotkey is the wrong choice please just say it. I just didn't know where to start.
Here is the code:

```
#SingleInstance, Force
SetTitleMatchMode, 2

InputBox, processName, Process Check, Enter the process name:
If (processName = "")
{
    MsgBox, No process name entered. Script will exit.
    ExitApp
}

If ProcessExist(processName)
{
    WinActivate, %processName%
    Sleep 100
    SendInput, This is a test text.
    Sleep 100
    SendInput, {Enter}
    MsgBox, Text sent to process "%processName%".
}
Else
{
    MsgBox, Process "%processName%" was not found.
}

ProcessExist(processName)
{
    Process, Exist, %processName%
    return ErrorLevel
}
```

Comment: Search for the Notepad process. Then (using P/Invoke), find its main window. Post a WM_SETTEXT message to that window. You can do some of this using Windows Forms, but you are likely going to need to P/Invoke some of it. If you want to _add_ the text to the end of what's there, get the existing text (with WM_GETTEXT), append your text and then set it

Comment: this can be done in any language. Since you are using curly braces, i removed the `python` tag....

Comment: According to the syntax this is neither javascript nor C# so I removed both tags